# hlookup - approximate match and structured reference tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have values in my Excel spreadsheet that look like this

```
      100    200    300
10     A      B      C
20     D      E      F
30     G      H      I
```

This gives me the correct answer:

```
=hlookup(120,B1:D4,2,TRUE)
```

But if I 'format as table', the same formula gives me #N/A.

I'd like to have it formatted as a table but I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Did your formula change B1:D1 into Table1[[#Headers]? btw, that formula looks like it should be =hlookup(120, B1:D4, 2, TRUE).

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the formula. 

It didn't automatically change it to Table1[#Headers] but if I do that manually it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes but it also put a text value like *Column1* into A1 and changed the 100, 200, 300 into text-that-looks-like-numbers instead of real numbers. I was kinda hoping you would notice that.

Comment: I did notice that. I tried changing column 1 to 0 and  =HLOOKUP("120",Table1[#Headers],2,TRUE) but still not working. I also tried converting the text to numbers but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 120 (as a true number) in F1,

```
=HLOOKUP(TEXT(F1, "0;@"), Table2[[#All],[100]:[300]], 2, TRUE)
'... or,
=HLOOKUP(TEXT(F1, "0;@"), B:D, 2, TRUE)
```

Hardcoding 120 into the formula,

```
=HLOOKUP("120", Table2[[#All],[100]:[300]], 2, TRUE)
'... or,
=HLOOKUP("120", B:D, 2, TRUE)
```